# Stack Implementation - Random Forest & Linear Regression cross_val_score

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I use a stack of RF and LR as follows:

```
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=3)

for train_index, test_index in tscv.split(X):
   print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
   X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
   y_train, y_test = Y[train_index], Y[test_index]


# build a pure Random Forest
rf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=1, n_jobs=-1,verbose=3,n_estimators=20).fit(X_train, y_train)
y_rf = rf.predict(X_test)


# build a pure linear model
linear = HuberRegressor().fit(X_train, y_train)
y_lin = linear.predict(X_test)

#build a stack of two models
lin_resid = y_train - cross_val_score(linear, X_train, y_train,verbose=5,n_jobs=-1)
rf.fit(X_train, lin_resid)
y_stack = y_lin + rf.predict(X_test)
```

I want to use cross_val_score and get the following error:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes
>   (62964,) (3,)

Why is that?

cross_val_predict works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cross_val_score` method returns an "Array of scores of the estimator for each run of the cross validation."

So in your example

```
cross_val_score(linear, X_train, y_train,verbose=5,n_jobs=-1)
```

is a vector of shape `(3,)`

And your `y_train` is a vector of shape `(62964,)`.

So the dimensions of your two vectors do not match when you try do :

```
lin_resid = y_train - cross_val_score(linear, X_train, y_train,verbose=5,n_jobs=-1)
```

That's why you get this error message.

On the other hand, `cross_val_predict` returns a vector of same shape as your `y_train` that's why it works.

Comment: Thanks! How should it look correct to work with cross_val_score?

Comment: use `cross_val_predict`